# i can't limit programmer in tfs (team foundation server)

Tags: tfs, permissions

How can i set permission for programmer in my team project that they can just check-in and if they code had conflict they can't select which one is better and admin see the conflict and select best choice for it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't trust your developers to resolve conflicts.  My best advice would be to invest in training and mentoring to change that.

Other options you have is to put in place good testing practices and a code review policy to help catch any potential mistakes.

Alternatively, you could have each developer work in their own personal branch, and leave it up to an admin to perform merges into MAIN.

Comment: +1.. I agree with 1st 2 points. Personal branch is not a good practice unless it's absolutely required..